# display image using php from phpmyadmin for product items not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am putting links for my book items in mysql phpmyadmin. All images are stored in img folder in htdocs. I cannot seem to display those images.

/I read book infor first from database

```
<?php

include ("db_con.php");


//read all books
$book_query= "select * from book";

$run_query=mysqli_query($dbcon, $book_query);

$isbn=array();
$author=array();
$book=array();
$page=array();
$weight=array();
$publisher=array();
$edition=array();
$language=array();
$img=array();



if(mysqli_num_rows($run_query)>0)  
{


    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $run_query)){

        array_push($isbn,$row['isbn']);
        array_push($author,$row['author']);
        array_push($book,$row['book']);
        array_push($page,$row['page']);
        array_push($weight,$row['weight']);
        array_push($publisher,$row['publisher']);
        array_push($edition,$row['edition']);
        array_push($language,$row['language']);
        array_push($img,$row['img']);


    }
    //echo "$img[0]";
    //print_r($img);

}


mysqli_close($dbcon);


?>
```

then I try to display it

```
<?php include ("local_book_db.php"); ?>
<section id="recommended">
        <p id="typeNew">Recommended</p>

        <a href=""><img src="$img[0]" alt="aaa">a book</a>



    </section>
```

It only displays the alt string not the image How can I display the image?

Thanks

Comment: can you show the book table

Comment: From PHPMyAdmin? You do know that PHPMyAdmin simply is an application where you can _manage_ MySQL databases in? If you're writing your own application, it has nothing to do with PHPMyAdmin. The actual database is just MySQL.

Comment: Why are you creating multiple arrays? Isn't better to have one multidimensional array?

Answer (score 0):

You need to 'echo' the image url, which I'm assuming is in the $img array.

The correct code is :

```
 <a href=""><img src="<?php echo $img[0]; ?>" alt="aaa">a book</a>
```

Hope this helps! This code only work if the $img is an array and $img[0] holds the image url.